# Position of integers in vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I think the question is pretty basic, but still keeps me busy since some time.

Lets assume we have a vector containing 4 integers randomly repetetive, like:

```
v = [ 1 3 3 3 4 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 4 3 3 4 2 2]
```

I am searching for the vector of all positions of each integer, e.g. for 1 it should be a vector like:

```
position_one = [1 7 13]
```

Since I want to search every row of a 100x10000 matrix I was not able to deal with linear indeces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: will `position_one = find(v==1)` do the work for you or you need something more sophisticated?

Comment: my problem with find was that sub2ind had problem with the linear indices and I couldnt figure out why ;) but I'll try going with the second answer, since I have already started something similar.....thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rows and columns**

Since your output for every integer changes, a cell array will fit the whole task. For the whole matrix, you can do something like:

```
A = randi(4,10,30); % some data
Row = repmat((1:size(A,1)).',1,size(A,2)); % index of the row
Col = repmat((1:size(A,2)),size(A,1),1); % index of the column
pos = @(n) [Row(A==n) Col(A==n)]; % Anonymous function to find the indices of 'n'
```

than for every `n` you can write:

```
>> pos(3)
ans =
     1     1
     2     1
     5     1
     6     1
     9     1
     8     2
     3     3
     .     .
     .     .
     .     .
```

where the first column is the row, and the second is the column for every instance of `n` in `A`.

And for all `n`s you can use an `arrayfun`:

```
positions = arrayfun(pos,1:max(A(:)),'UniformOutput',false) % a loop that goes over all n's
```

or a simple `for` loop (faster):

```
positions = cell(1,max(A(:)));
for n = 1:max(A(:))
    positions(n) = {pos(n)};
end
```

The output in both cases would be a cell array:

```
positions = 
    [70x2 double]    [78x2 double]    [76x2 double]    [76x2 double]
```

and for every `n` you can write `positions{n}`, to get for example:

```
>> positions{1}
ans =
    10     1
     2     3
     5     3
     3     4
     5     4
     1     5
     4     5
     .     .
     .     .
     .     .
```

**Only rows**

If all you want in the column index per a given row and `n`, you can write this:

```
A = randi(4,10,30);
row_pos = @(k,n) A(k,:)==n;
positions = false(size(A,1),max(A(:)),size(A,2));
for n = 1:max(A(:))
    positions(:,n,:) = row_pos(1:size(A,1),n);
end
```

now, `positions` is a logical 3-D array, that every row corresponds to a row in `A`, every column corresponds to a value of `n`, and the third dimension is the presence vector for the combination of row and `n`. this way, we can define `R` to be the column index:

```
R = 1:size(A,2);
```

and then find the relevant positions for a given row and `n`. For instance, the column indices of `n=3` in row 9 is:

```
>> R(positions(9,3,:))
ans =
     2     6    18    19    23    24    26    27
```

this would be just like calling `find(A(9,:)==3)`, but if you need to perform this many times, the finding all indices and store them in `positions` (which is logical so it is not so big) would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Find linear indexes in a matrix: `I = find(A == 1)`.
Find two dimensional indexes in matrix A: `[row, col] = find(A == 1)`.

```
%Create sample matrix, with elements equal one:
A = zeros(5, 4);
A([2 10 14]) = 1

A =

     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
```

Find ones as linear indexes in A:

```
find(A == 1)

ans =

     2
    10
    14

%This is the same as reshaping A to a vector and find ones in the vector:
B = A(:);
find(B == 1);

B' =

     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Find two dimensional indexes:

```
[row, col] = find(A == 1)

row =

     2
     5
     4


col =

     1
     2
     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) using an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as follows:

```
positions = accumarray(v(:), 1:numel(v), [], @(x) {sort(x.')});
```

For

```
v = [ 1 3 3 3 4 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 4 3 3 4 2 2];
```

this gives

```
positions{1} =
     1     7    13
positions{2} =
     6     8    12    18    19
positions{3} =
     2     3     4     9    11    15    16
positions{4} =
     5    10    14    17
```